# How to add user from front end

Tags: users

These all things are about WordPress,
I want to know that how to give permission to "Subscriber" to add another user having a role "shopper" (I have already made a shopper role using code in function.php

```
add_role('shopper', __(
    'Shopper'),
    array(
        'read' => true, // Allows a user to read
        )
    );
```

and also want to know how to do all this like:\

- How to make a form in the front end for subscribers to add shoppers,
- How to add more fields like i also want some custom fields in forms which Subscribers can fill while adding Shoppers like Date Of Birth, Age etc.
- Subscriber can also be able to see the list of shoppers he added.
- This shopper will lie under that subscriber who will add him and other subscribers will not be able to see the list of the shopper or other subscribers.

Can anybody help me in this.

Comment: What has your research turned up so far? What have you attempted for yourself?